# ASP.Net, populate grid record by record

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a GridView on the page and some search option on top of the page and a search button,
When user click Search button, get first record and bind the grid and show to the user.
Now start getting remaining records (5 at a time) and add to the grid until entire search result.
Is that possible with asp.net and jQuery, If yes, please suggest me how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to (theoretically) read an HTTP stream and output results directly to the browser as they come in. **Do not do this.**

I would suggest that you just add paging support to your `GridView` and look into optimizing your database query/data binding procedures. There are [many other answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gridview%20paging) that cover `GridView` paging.

Comment: I know how to get the paged data but some time we need to show more records on page like 500 records on the page and then we face the problem of page load timing
Anyway, thanks for your reply

Comment: @AliAdravi, can you explain how you currently save the data from the database? Are you storing it in cache, `Session`, or something else?

Answer (score -1):

I assumed you get your data from a DB. You can set the filter in your datasource's selectcommand in the page_load, like this:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * from Table1"
                    + " WHERE (Field1 LIKE '%" + filter + "%'"
                    + " OR Field2 LIKE '%" + filter + "%')";
```

As for the 5 record at a time, you can set your PageSize to 5.

Comment: this doesn't resolve the paging issue because paging would be happening in the markup and the entire result set would be stored in viewstate. instead you want to page as the database level. and preferably not using table scans to query the db.